# How to iterate a sequence from both ends?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, iterable

I want to iterate (part of) a Python sequence "from both ends" (to the middle (of that part), here).
In C/C++/Java, I might try

```
int start = 2, beyond = 7;
for (int forward = start, back = beyond ; forward <= --back ; forward++)
    printf("%d %d\n", forward, back);
```

I can't seem to decide which of the following variants I dislike best:

```
seq = tuple(chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))
start, beyond = 2, 7

print("subtract")
for forward in range(start, beyond):
    back = start + beyond - 1 - forward
    if (back < forward):
        break
    print(seq[forward], seq[back])
#    if (back <= forward): XXX ERROR, as YvesgereY pointed out
#        break
print("reversed")
for forward, back in zip(range(start, beyond),
                         reversed(range(start, beyond))):
    if (back < forward):
        break
    print(seq[forward], seq[back])
print("step -1")
for forward, back in zip(range(start, beyond), range(beyond-1, start-1, -1)):
    if (back < forward):
        break
    print(seq[forward], seq[back])
print("naked code")
forward, back = start, beyond-1 # thanks again, YvesgereY
while (forward <= back):
    print(seq[forward], seq[back])
    forward += 1
    back -= 1
```

Is there a pleasing/sane/idiomatic way to handle this?

Comment: The last solution gets done what you want using the least number of new words (`zip`, `range`, `reversed`). By many definitions, it's the best.

Comment: I've seen four answers with solid advice. I hope you don't mind losing points from an up-vote now when I downvote the answer I accept - just to keep the difference to the others in check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not `zip` the list with the reverse of itself?

```
mid = (len(lst) + 1) // 2   
for x, y in zip(lst[:mid], lst[::-1]):
     print((x, y))

(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
```

`zip` automatically handles lists of different lengths, just make sure you set the midpoint properly (it depends on whether the list is evenly sized or not).

Comment: I think `mid = (len(lst)+1) // 2` is more idiomatic/legible.

Comment: `Why not zip the list with the reverse of itself` uncertain about the cost of slicing&zipping. Indexing sequences to iterate them doesn't feel quite right in the first place, see the second part of [Moses Koledoye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064570/3789665).

Comment: @greybeard `enumerate` also happens to create a copy. This happens to be yet another pythonic approach.

Comment: Oh, I missed the first point: `Why not zip the list with the reverse of itself` didn't think of it - it clearly is the more direct alternative to zipping the ranges of indices for the scenario I set.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather write:

```
size = max((beyond-start+1)//2,0)  # 0 if start>beyond
for i in range(0,size):
   print(start+i,beyond-i-1)
```

Note that your `substract` and `step -1` versions are incorrect since they would allow `forward>back` in the last iteration.

You can slightly improve the `while` version by emphasizing the loop condition (making off-by-one error less likely):

```
forward, back = start, beyond-1
while forward <= back:
    print(forward, back)
    forward += 1
    back -= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the last method using the while loop is the best:

```
forward, back = start, beyond
while (forward < back):
    back -= 1
    print(forward, back)
    forward += 1
```

It's it's concise but still, readable, has clear semantics, and seems to be the most 'Pythonic' compared to the other methods that have several levels of function call nesting. You could improve it by wrapping it in a generator:

```
def iterate_to_middle(start_front, start_end):
    while start_front < start_end:
        start_end -= 1
        yield start_front, start_end
        start_front += 1
```

It could then be used like so:

```
>>> for indexes in iterate_to_middle(2, 7):
    print(indexes)


(2, 6)
(3, 5)
(4, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably overthinking this. The `while` loop is ok.

Additionally, sequence types in Python support **negative indexing**, which I think  eases up things. Here's an approach that uses `enumerate` to generate the negative corresponding index for each forward item:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1):
    print(x, lst[-i])
    if i * 2 >= len(lst): break
```

---

```
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Using `enumerate` with negative indices is also a nice choice. +1

Comment: I'd have to slice to get the benefit of negative indices. Doesn't look half bad, actually.

Comment: @greybeard That ain't slicing, it's indexing. One item, *O* (1), as opposed to slicing *k* items, *O* (k).

Comment: How do I do without slicing when the part to be iterated neither starts at `0` nor ends at `len(seq)`? (It's not even "symmetrical" half of the times.)

Comment: @greybeard Just got your point. Well, memory issues aside, slicing reads better and probably performs better than most of the approaches you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ~ operator to get (index + 1) * -1.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range((len(arr) + 1) // 2):
    print(arr[i], arr[~i])

1 5
2 4
3 3
```