# how would I find if numbers in an array are equal to each other in python

Tags: python, arrays, similarity

If I had an array formed for example [1,2,3,4,5,6], how would I be able to check if 1 and 6 are equal and then 2 and 5 and then 3 and 4 etc without knowing how many numbers in my array that I have? Finding if the array is symmetric

The data set is being generated randomly from different molecules so the data isn't consistent and I am trying to work this out for each molecule.

Comment: Do you mean if all the elements in array are equal or the array is "symmetric"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate a sequence from both ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064448/how-to-iterate-a-sequence-from-both-ends)

Comment: @notnotparas if the array is symmetric

Comment: @user6104134, Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def checkList(numbers):
    for i in range(len(numbers)//2+1):
        j = len(numbers) -i -1
        print(i,j)
        if i<j:
            if numbers[i] != numbers[j]:
                return False
    return True
    
print(checkList([1,2,3,2,1]))
```

We set two pointers. One is from the start and the other one is from the end. both are moving to the middle while checking each pointer's elements are equal until the middle.

Comment: It comes up with this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: shall you share the input

Comment: okay this is working now i just had to change my own code

Answer (score 0):

Most Pythonic Way:

```py
def solve(arr,n):
   return all(a[i]==a[n-i-1] for i in range(n))
```

Comment: Nice in one line but it will give so much errors like name and index error